# Python eval a string representing dictionary containing network path (backslashes), weird behavior or expected?

Tags: python, eval, backslash

I am trying to eval a string that represents a dictionary and I am not sure why the eval is producing result that looks incorrect to me unless there is something I am missing.

Here is the eval

```
>>> a =  "{'a':'\\\\my_host\\my_path'}"
>>> a
"{'a':'\\\\my_host\\my_path'}"
>>> eval(a)
{'a': '\\my_host\\my_path'}
>>>
```

The processing of the backslash characters by the eval looks incorrect. The 4 backslashes before my_host are converted into 2 backslashes. But the 2 backslashes before my_path is still 2 backslashes.

What am I missing here? How can I properly eval a string representing dictionary where the values represent a network path?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide one more backslash, like this -

`a =  "{'a':'\\\\\my_host\\my_path'}"`

This is because in `\\\\m` 1st `\` from left gets consumed in escaping the `\` after it. Hence to protect the first backslash, we need to add one more before that.

or if you don't want all this fuss you can use `r` for raw string, like -

`a =  "{'a':r'\\\\my_host\\my_path'}"`

This won't consider any character as special.

```
>>> a =  "{'a':r'\\\\my_host\\my_path'}"
>>> eval(a)
{'a': '\\\\my_host\\my_path'}
>>> a =  "{'a':'\\\\\my_host\\my_path'}"
>>> eval(a)
{'a': '\\\\my_host\\my_path'}
```

Comment: The raw string literal is straightforward and I am using it. I am still confused by the 5 backslash solution. I would have thought that if backslash was treated special then the original eval(a) should have resulted in {'a': '\\my_host\my_path'}. I am clearly missing how it works.

Comment: odd number of backslashes are usually bad unless you need to enter special characters. Check my answer bellow, where I explain how escaping play with `eval`

Answer (score 0):

Backslashes combined with `eval` can be really tricky.
First consider these two strings:

```
>>> "\m"
"\\m"
>>> "\\m"
"\\m"
```

They both produce the same output. In the first case first backslash tries to consume next character, but `m` is not a special character. Therefore, backslash remains a single backslash (raw: `\m`). In normal strings backslashes are escaped, so Python escapes it for you.
In the second case first backslash escapes second backslash, so we have a single backslash (raw: `\m`) which Python escapes for you.

Now, let's move to more backslashes. Consider a raw string `\a`. To get a single backslash we need to escape it in out string, so we need to evaluate a raw string `\\a`

```
>>> eval(r'"\\a"')
'\\a'
```

Which is indeed raw `\a`. However, if our initial string is not raw, Python performs first escaping before calling `eval` which gives

```
>>> eval('"\\a"')
'\x07'
```

Not what we need. What happened here? First, Python takes out string `"\\a"` and uses first backslash to escape second backslash. We end up with string `"\a"` which gets evaluated. Python looks for special characters again and treats `\a` as a special ASCII character `BEL`.

If wee want to have the same output is in the first example we need four backslashes. First and second are consumed to one backslash, third and fourth to another backslash, so we end up with `\\a` which is evaluated to raw `\a`

```
>>> eval('"\\\\a"')
'\\a'
```

Exactly what we need.

You should never leave odd number of backslashes because it can cause unexpected things. e.g.

```
>>> eval("{'a':'\\\\\my_host\\my_path'}")
{'a': '\\\\my_host\\my_path'}
```

Apparently it works fine, but what if the name started with `b`

```
>>> eval("{'a':'\\\\\by_host\\by_path'}")
{'a': '\\\x08y_host\x08y_path'}
```

Ugh...

The correct way to do this is:

```
>>> eval("{'a':'\\\\\\\\by_host\\\\by_path'}")
{'a': '\\\\by_host\\by_path'}
```

After double escaping, each four backslashes are merged into one, so our path is now `\\by_host\by_path` as we need.